# Help understanding proof of "All bounded monotone sequence converge" lemma

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

As written down in [PlanetMath](https://planetmath.org/proofofbolzanoweierstrasstheorem):

> **All bounded monotone sequences converge.**
>
> Proof: Let $ (s_n) $ be a bounded, non-decreasing sequence. Let S denote the set $ \{s_n:n∈N \} $. Then let $ b = sup(S) $ (the supremum of S.)
> Choose some $ \epsilon > 0 $. Then there is a corresponding $ N $ such that $ s_N > b - \epsilon $. Since $ (s_n) $ is non-decreasing, for all $ n > N $, $s_n > b − \epsilon $. But $ (s_n) $ is bounded, so we have $ b− \epsilon < s_n \leq b $. But this implies $ |s_n−b|< \epsilon $, so $ \lim s_n = b. $ □

Now, trying to understand the proof if I choose the following bounded, non-decreasing sequence:

$$ s = (1,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6.5, 6.6, 6.7, 6.9, 7) $$

Then, $ S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6.5, 6.6, 6.7, 6.9, 7 \}$ and the supremum is $ b = 7 $.

I now choose an $ \epsilon = 0.1 $, then the proof mentions there must be exist an N such that $ S_N > b - \epsilon $, that N is $ 11 $ as:

$$ S_{11} = 7 > 7 - 0.1 = 6.9 $$

However, here's the step where I can't proceed with my example, "For all $ n \gt N $", N = 11 is the last element of the sequence, there's no n = 12 as there's no $ s_{12} $.

Should the proof say $ n \geq N $, or am I approaching this incorrectly?

Comment: Huh? A sequence means an *infinite* list of real numbers.

Comment: A sequence means that there is an infinite number of elements. Your $s$ is a set

Comment: A sequence can have a finite length: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Sequence

Comment: I've always thought that Theorems like, "All bounded monotone sequences converge" are talking about infinite sequences only, but maybe I am wrong about that. But I think the theorem in the question is intended to be about infinite sequences only. I think this because the, "for all $n>N$" part of your proof makes sense for infinite sequences but not for finite sequences (also called "tuples"), as you pointed out.

Comment: Talking about finite sequences and convergence or boundedness is pretty useless. Since, every finite sequence is bounded and the term convergence is not really useful. Are you sure your professor included finite sequences in her/his definition of a sequence? Nevertheless, in your proof they explicitely talk about infinite sequences in the phrase "Let S denote the set $\{s_n | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$".

Comment: Hi, @Saimel. I don't have any professor. I'm just not assuming anything about the sequence more than the basic definition of it being an enumerated collection of objects (so it could finite or infinite). However, your last point seems convincing to indicate that it must be talking about an infinite sequence. Although I wouldn't say is explicit for the untrained eye (no more that calling infinite sequence instead of sequence, anyway)

Comment: IIRC, in analysis a _sequence_ always, in my experience, connotes a mapping from the natural numbers into a set, i.e., an infinite sequence.